# AJAX Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am getting the error when trying to run m3u8 video :: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Video</title>

    <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js"></script>
    <script src="https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-media-sources/releases/download/v0.1.0/videojs-media-sources.js"></script>
    <script src="https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls/releases/download/v0.11.2/videojs.hls.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<h1>Video</h1>

<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="268"
       data-setup='{}'>

    <source src="http://my~server.com/recordings/91/2015-12-15/91_1450161600/91_1450161600.m3u8" type='application/x-mpegURL'>


</video>

<script>
    var player = videojs('my_video_1');
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

On `http://my~server.com/` I have added `.htaccess` but it didn't work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

   RewriteEngine on
   <IfModule mod_headers.c>
                Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
        Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
   </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any PHP handling the request of your video? You can control the actual headers sent before the "video stream" starts.

I'm not sure that the .htaccess you have right there will cover the subfolders you are referring to as well.